# Is there a fan in the new Airport Extreme?

Tags: hardware, airport

I'm wondering if there is a fan in Apple's Airport Extreme wireless router so that I can plan for a low noise environment. Is there any source measuring the noise from this part or documenting the internal construction?

- http://store.apple.com/us/product/ME918/airport-extreme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. See [this article](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/AirPort_Extreme_A1521_Troubleshooting) on ifixit.com for instance.

Comment: I have set up a few of these. they are **very** quiet. I've never noticed the fan. In warmer environments it might be noticeable tho...